# How to sum a column with a foreign value selecting by id

Tags: php, mysql

I've a table syntax like this,

```
- table1

id    foreign_table_id
-----------------------
1     2
2     2
3     2
4     1
5     1
6     1
```

The other table is,

```
- table2

id    value
------------
1     20
2     10
```

I want to get a summation of table1.foreign_table_id where the data will retrieve from table2.

> Like this example should produce the result **90**

Please provide any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below query.

```
Select sum(table2.value) as total FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.foreign_table_id = table2.id
```

It will give u below result.

### Output::

```
total
-----
90
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT SUM(table2.value) AS summation FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 
ON table2.id = table1.foreign_table_id
```